# How to make the attached files opened with their convenient programs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, email, file-upload

I attach some files to the Email through the following method :

```
if (rad_upload.UploadedFiles != null && rad_upload.UploadedFiles.Count > 0)
{

    foreach (UploadedFile file in rad_upload.UploadedFiles)
    {
        Attachment f = new Attachment(file.InputStream, 
                                      MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        attach.Add(f);
    }
}

Contact_List.sendMail(mail, lbl_depEmailValue.Text.TrimEnd(), 
password, txt_sub.Text, msg.ToString(), int.Parse(dep.Main_code.ToString()),
attach);
```

---

And in the **sendMail** method :

```
if (attachments != null && attachments.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Attachment a in attachments)
    {
        mail.Attachments.Add(a);
    }
}
```

---

Every thing goes okay , but i wanna to know how to let the uploaded file opened with its convenient program automatically .

For example :

The `pdf` files opened automatically with acrobat reader if installed when double clicking on the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to set the `ContentType` of yours `Attachments`

[MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms144614.aspx)

Comment: `Attachment f = new Attachment(file.InputStream, file.ContentType);`

Comment: maybe the problem is when you are saving the file in the server